# Difficulties in Capturing an ID

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'll try to be clear. I'm using Selenium to initiate a session on a webpage, input some data, and click on some buttons. However, when it reaches the boleto (bank slip) page and I need to locate the boleto button, which has a class indicating its status, it simply can't find the button, resulting in the following error:  `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="btn-pagar-com-boleto"]"}`

Could there be an issue with the Selenium session? It changes the link when transitioning from the search page to the boleto page.

Here's the code attempting to locate the boleto payment button:

```
# Boleto payment button ID
botao_pagamento_id = 'btn-pagar-com-boleto'

# Find the element
elemento_pagamento = driver.find_element(By.ID, botao_pagamento_id)

# Wait until the element is present on the page with a longer timeout
try:
    # Use XPath to locate the element
    elemento_pagamento = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn-pagar-com-boleto"]'))
    )

    # Wait until the button state is modified by JavaScript events
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        lambda driver: 'botao desabilitado' not in elemento_pagamento.get_attribute('class').split()
    )

    # Check if the class is 'botao desabilitado'
    if 'botao desabilitado' in elemento_pagamento.get_attribute('class').split():
        print("Checked")
        realizar_acao_por_id(driver, 'btn-voltar')
        clicar_entendi(driver)
    else:
        # Perform a specific action
        print("Not checked")
        realizar_acao_por_id(driver, 'btn-pagar')
        elemento_codigo_barras_id = 'linkCodigoBarras'
        valor_data_codigo = driver.find_element(By.ID, elemento_codigo_barras_id).find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('data-codigo')
        realizar_acao_por_id(driver, 'btn-voltar')
        clicar_entendi(driver)

except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print(f"Error in iteration 0: Element not found - {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error in iteration 0: {e}")
```

Here is the HTML element:

```
<div id="btn-pagar-com-boleto" class="botao ">
                    <div class="imagem boleto"></div>
                    <div class="textoBotao"><p>Boleto Bancário</p>
                        <p>Pagamento somente à vista</p></div>
                </div>
```

I tried to find the button and check if its class had a specific name. If it did, it would proceed to another block and perform other functions.

Comment: You are looking for two words in the set of classes, but you did a `.split()`.  That output will never have two words separated by a space -- they would be two separate strings.